# Problema com write e read na linguagem Pascal

Tags: algoritmo, pascal

Olá, escrevi um algoritmo simples em Pascal para calcular a média das idades, porém quando paso o comando read da vaiável "nome2", ao invés do programa permitir inputar dados, o programa pula para o read da variável "idade2". Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

```
program idades;
var
    nome1, nome2: string;
    idade1, idade2: integer;
    media: real;

begin
writeln('Dados da primeira pessoa: ');
write('Nome: ');
read(nome1);
write('Idade: ');
read(idade1);

writeln('Dados da segunda pessoa: ');
write('Nome: '); read(nome2);
write('Idade: '); read(idade2);

media := (idade1 + idade2) / 2;
writeln('A media de idade de ', nome1, ' e ', nome2, ' = ', media:3:2);

end.
```

Para não ter que instalar nenhum compilador, existem vários sites que compilam online. Se alguém puder me falar o que falta nesse algoritmo, me ajudaria bastante.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Cara, eu não sei explicar o motivo, mas poderia fazer a leitura dos valores usando a função [readln](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html)

Comment: Eu havia tentado isso também, mas infelizmente não funcionou com o readln. Me parece muito estranho o algoritmo simlesmente pular o comando. Obrigado a ajuda.

Comment: Usando o [readln](https://gist.github.com/danizavtz/4ec60bfd236ee0fd396adc379c94e4db) eu não consegui reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Fiz a alteração e coloquei readln em todos os reads, e realmente funcionou. Agora o estranho é o porque funcionou apenas desse modo?! hahaha, muito obrigado a ajuda